# Casting a mp2t stream to Chromecast

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, chromecast, google-cast

I'm developing a project where I receive data from an external mp2t stream in a node.js app and I'm trying to cast it to a chromecast device using the [castv2-client](https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2-client) package setting the *contentType* attribute to "video/mp2t" but it's not working.

If I convert the stream to an mp4 file using [ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) I can cast the video, but it stutters a lot given the fact that on each chunk of video received, it has to convert it.

Is there any way I can cast the mp2t video directly as I receive it?

Comment: I don't think that `video/mp2t` is supported. You may check the [Supported Media for Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) documentation. Also, if you're having problems playing streams on a Cast device, it may be an issue with CORS. Use a publicly available CORS proxy server to test your streams.

Comment: @abielita If you look at the link you provided, `MP2T` is listed under `Media container formats`. They doesn't mention which codecs they support in any particular container, which I guess means that any of the codecs listed below that is valid in any particular container should be supported. The information is insufficient to the point of useless.